# Expect script inside bash script optional statement

Tags: script, embedded, bash-scripting, expect

Using: `CentOS 6.2` `BASH shell`

My script is something along the lines of

```
#!/bin/bash
INSTALL_PATH="Enter install path"
CR="\n"
/bin/su root -c "/usr/bin/expect << EOF
spawn name.run
expect $INSTALL_PATH
send $CR
EOF; ... do more stuff..."
```

Now sometimes my name.run file asks "Would you like to uninstall?" how can I send this as an optional argument after the first send?

Comment: also asked on stackoverflow -- http://stackoverflow.com/q/10150939/7552

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put multiple patterns inside an `expect` command

```
spawn name.run
expect $INSTALL_PATH
send \r
expect {
  {Would you like to uninstall?} {
    send yes\r
    exp_continue 
  }
  eof 
}
```

Take note that you send "\r" to "hit enter".

Also, the terminal word for a here-doc **must** appear by itself on a line -- it cannot be followed by "; more stuff"

Comment: Cool, will try this out and get back to you if it works as I'm shooting for.

Comment: I received a `"invalid command name "/usr/bin/expect"`... it seems like the EOF (see above) is being skipped with the conditional expect is ignored.  Do I need to keep a second EOF after your closing brace??

Comment: the lower case `eof` I have in my answer is for expect. The upper case `EOF` in your question is for the shell to terminate the here-doc

Comment: Ah, so in other words I need both, right?  (The `EOF` for the here-doc and the `eof` for the embedded expect script, correct?)  I really appreciate the help!  Going to test it out now...

Comment: WOOO!  Once I added that EOF back in everything worked like a charm.  Your conditional expect, combined with the timeout proofing of Niall Byrne made the script work perfectly.... unintendended CUDA install is working perfectly. :)

Here's Byrne's post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150939/formatting-expect-script-inside-of-user-command-in-bash-script